# When are harmony exports generated by Webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack, ecmascript-harmony, immer

I have an angular config that output that outputs among others :

```
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   Immer: () => (/* binding */ Immer2),
/* harmony export */   applyPatches: () => (/* binding */ applyPatches),
/* harmony export */   castDraft: () => (/* binding */ castDraft),
/* harmony export */   castImmutable: () => (/* binding */ castImmutable),
/* harmony export */   createDraft: () => (/* binding */ createDraft),
/* harmony export */   current: () => (/* binding */ current),
/* harmony export */   enableMapSet: () => (/* binding */ enableMapSet),
/* harmony export */   enablePatches: () => (/* binding */ enablePatches),
/* harmony export */   finishDraft: () => (/* binding */ finishDraft),
/* harmony export */   freeze: () => (/* binding */ freeze),
/* harmony export */   immerable: () => (/* binding */ DRAFTABLE),
/* harmony export */   isDraft: () => (/* binding */ isDraft),
/* harmony export */   isDraftable: () => (/* binding */ isDraftable),
/* harmony export */   nothing: () => (/* binding */ NOTHING),
/* harmony export */   original: () => (/* binding */ original),
/* harmony export */   produce: () => (/* binding */ produce),
/* harmony export */   produceWithPatches: () => (/* binding */ produceWithPatches),
/* harmony export */   setAutoFreeze: () => (/* binding */ setAutoFreeze),
/* harmony export */   setUseStrictShallowCopy: () => (/* binding */ setUseStrictShallowCopy)
/* harmony export */ });
```

This is the export from the library `immer`.

I'm trying to reproduce that part with the harmony exports but without any luck.

[Stackblitz repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-terser-uvczrw?file=README.md).

When does webpack produce these kind of output (the harmony exports) ?
Can you help me achieve something similar on the stackblitz ?